# SQL command to split by "/"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, split

I have a data column with values like this:

table: type

```
ID|Descriptions  
1 |chair/table/plates/  
2 |chair2/table2/plates2/
```

What will be the SQL command to split it by "/" ?

Expected output

```
ID|Description1|Description2|Description3|  
1 |chair       |table       |plates  
2 |chair2      |table2      |plates2
```

Comment: will this description have only 3 `/`?

Comment: more than 3 there are cases 3 or 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH Split_Descr ([ID],[Descriptions], xmldescr)
AS
(
    SELECT [ID],
    [Descriptions],
    CONVERT(XML,'<Descr><desc>'  
    + REPLACE([Descriptions],'/', '</desc><desc>') + '</desc></Descr>') AS xmldescr
      FROM Table1
)

 SELECT [ID],      
 xmldescr.value('/Descr[1]/desc[1]','varchar(100)') AS Descr1,    
 xmldescr.value('/Descr[1]/desc[2]','varchar(100)') AS Descr2,
 xmldescr.value('/Descr[1]/desc[3]','varchar(100)') AS Descr3
 FROM Split_Descr
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51c2a)